# Flutter app crashed during image upload through image_picker plugin

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter. Recently started an app where an image needs to be uploaded from mobile to server (no firebase) through PHP. I am using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin with it. Code works fine sometimes but sometime app crashes on image select after few seconds. Below is sample of code.

Code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:my_app/includes/functions.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
bool _ignoreChangeImageButton = false;
String _status = '', _oldImageName = '';

// Other Code

Future<void> _getImage() async {
    try{
        final XFile? xFile = await _imagePicker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery,
            maxWidth: 300,
            maxHeight: 300,
            imageQuality: 90
        );
        if(xFile == null) return;
        setState(() {
            _status = 'Uploading..';
            _ignoreChangeImageButton = true;
        });
        _uploadImage(base64Encode(File(xFile.path).readAsBytesSync()), xFile.path.split('/').last);
    } catch(e) {
        debugPrint('Error: ' + e.toString());
    }
}

Future<void> _uploadImage(String newImageData, String newImageName) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> dpData = {
        'oldImageName': _oldImageName,
        'newImageData': newImageData,
        'newImageName': newImageName,
        'userDisplayId': widget.data['userDisplayId']
    };
    final dpDataResponse = await Functions.postAndGetData('https://www.xyzabc.com/app/ajax/upload_dp.php', dpData);
    if(dpDataResponse.isNotEmpty){
        if(dpDataResponse['status'] == 'No Internet'){
            Functions.showToast('No Internet', 'Short');
            setState(() {
                _status = 'No Internet';
                _ignoreChangeImageButton = false;
            });
        } else if(dpDataResponse['status'] == 'Success'){
            Map<String, dynamic> dpSqlData = {
                'dp': dpDataResponse['url']
            };
            await AgentProfileCrud.updateAgentByDisplayId(int.parse(widget.data['userDisplayId']), dpSqlData);
            Functions.showToast('Image uploaded', 'Short');
            setState(() {
                _dp = dpDataResponse['url'];
                _status = 'Image Uploaded';
                _ignoreChangeImageButton = false;
                _oldImageName = dpDataResponse['url'].split('/').last;
            });
        } else {
            Functions.showToast('Error! Try again.', 'Short');
            setState(() {
                _status = 'Error! Try Again.';
                _ignoreChangeImageButton = false;
            });
        }
    } else {
        Functions.showToast('Error! Try again.', 'Short');
        setState(() {
            _status = 'Error! Try Again.';
            _ignoreChangeImageButton = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Following are Logcat Stacktraces:

```
2022-07-30 11:10:45.853 25022-25067/com.abcd.my_app A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 25067 (RenderThread), pid 25022 (app)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: Softversion: PD2060EF_EX_A_1.73.17
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: Time: 2022-07-30 11:10:46
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'vivo/2068/2034:11/RP1A.200720.012/compiler05301652:user/release-keys'
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2022-07-30 11:10:46+0530
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: pid: 25022, tid: 25067, name: RenderThread  >>> com.abcd.my_app <<<
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10287
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'drawRenderNode called on a context with no surface!'
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000061eb  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007a2195d210
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000007a2195ccc0  x5  0000007a2195ccc0  x6  0000007a2195ccc0  x7  0000000000000000
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  71d34b7f98a69bca  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000003  x14 0000000000000068  x15 35c17ee0635ce40e
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007b195c0948  x17 0000007b1959d750  x18 0000007a20ffc000  x19 00000000000061be
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x20 00000000000061eb  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000001  x23 0000000000000019
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000007a9522d085  x25 0000000000000001  x26 0000007a9524409a  x27 0000007a957fb000
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007b1b935340  x29 0000007a2195d290
2022-07-30 11:10:46.006 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:     lr  0000007b1954cd24  sp  0000007a2195d1f0  pc  0000007b1954cd50  pst 0000000000000000
2022-07-30 11:10:46.056 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000008cd50  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: ff7f50ccb22655aebeae64988ad917cc)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 000000000053210c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2340) (BuildId: 5fda5e28f341a49d92a58bf84bfbc3d6)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 000000000001394c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76) (BuildId: 41dc65e18251cf85250c40a648c62883)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000006d28  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336) (BuildId: eb6d64455c0ed3ef35210b47b13e1c71)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 000000000021a2d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::getFrame()+52) (BuildId: a86758b02dfe12dc43218a2a6a909c92)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0000000000222c44  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+404) (BuildId: a86758b02dfe12dc43218a2a6a909c92)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 0000000000225064  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+524) (BuildId: a86758b02dfe12dc43218a2a6a909c92)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 0000000000213818  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+208) (BuildId: a86758b02dfe12dc43218a2a6a909c92)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 000000000023571c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+88) (BuildId: a86758b02dfe12dc43218a2a6a909c92)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 0000000000015540  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+320) (BuildId: 20360938f20ad8c1b5b2c2a458915ae3)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 0000000000014db4  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+408) (BuildId: 20360938f20ad8c1b5b2c2a458915ae3)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 00000000000f450c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: ff7f50ccb22655aebeae64988ad917cc)
2022-07-30 11:10:46.057 25540-25540/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 000000000008ef34  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: ff7f50ccb22655aebeae64988ad917cc)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the error that shows up as it crashes? 
also await your _uploadImage() method when you call it.. its a future

Comment: @Danny, There is no error just says `runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...`, I am going to update to question complete logs now.

Comment: are you using the latest version of the package? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97267#issuecomment-1025908517 says here its been an issue but its been now resolved.

Comment: Yes, I guess its latest. I am using any instead of version. Moreover surprisingly app hasn't crashed since I have posted this question. I will wait and watch.

Comment: please share stack trace or error report from IDE

Comment: @MANISH stack traces updated

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have to switch to [File_Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker). No problems now.

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

Future<void> _getImage() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        allowMultiple: false,
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'heic', 'heif'],
    );
    if(result == null) return;
    final file = result.files.first;
    setState(() {
        _status = 'Uploading..';
        _ignoreChangeImageButton = true;
    });
    _uploadImage(base64Encode(File(file.path!).readAsBytesSync()), file.path!.split('/').last);
}
```